# SqlConnection error index 0 in c#

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

In the code below i see this error when i try to connect to connection string thiss error appears

Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

How can i fix it?
In the code below i see this error when i try to connect to connection string thiss error appears

Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

How can i fix it?

```
namespace InsertUserApp
{
    public partial class Home : Form
    {
        class ComboItemExample
        {
            public string DisplayString { get; set; }
            public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

            public override string ToString() { return DisplayString; }
        }
        private string connstring = "<default connection>";

        public Home()
        { 
            InitializeComponent();

            var srv1 = new ComboItemExample { DisplayString = "Srv1", ConnectionString = "Data Source=tcp:10.0.0.110;Initial Catalog=Database1;User ID=user;Password=pass;" };
            cmbSrv.Items.Add(srv1);

            var srv2 = new ComboItemExample { DisplayString = "Srv2", ConnectionString = "Data Source=tcp:10.1.0.11;Initial Catalog=Database2;User ID=user;Password=pass;" };
            cmbSrv.Items.Add(srv2);

            var srv3 = new ComboItemExample { DisplayString = "Srv3", ConnectionString = "Data Source=tcp:10.1.0.15;Initial Catalog=Database3;User ID=user;Password=pass" };
            cmbSrv.Items.Add(srv3);

        }


            private void txtID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                /*if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtID.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Plotesoni fushat UnID", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                }
                else
                {*/
                SqlCommand command1 =
                new SqlCommand("select * from Table1 WHERE Tag = 'User' and UnId = '" + txtID.Text + "'", connection);
                SqlCommand command2 =
                new SqlCommand("select * from Table1 WHERE Tag = 'Pass' and UnId = '" + txtID.Text + "'", connection);
                SqlCommand command3 =
                new SqlCommand("select * from Table1 WHERE Tag = 'Shifra1' and UnId = '" + txtID.Text + "'", connection);
                SqlCommand command4 =
                SqlCommand command5 =
                new SqlCommand("select * from Table2 WHERE UnId = '" + txtID.Text + "'", connection);
                connection.Open();

                SqlDataReader read1 = command1.ExecuteReader();


                while (read1.Read())
                {
                    txtID.Text = (read1["UnId"].ToString());
                    txtUser.Text = (read1["Value"].ToString());

                }
                read1.Close();
                SqlDataReader read2 = command2.ExecuteReader();
                while (read2.Read())
                {
                    txtPass.Text = (read2["Value"].ToString());
                }
                read2.Close();
                SqlDataReader read3 = command3.ExecuteReader();
                while (read3.Read())
                {
                    txtOrg.Text = (read3["Value"].ToString());
                }
                read3.Close();
                SqlDataReader read5 = command5.ExecuteReader();
                while (read5.Read())
                {
                    txtgrp.Text = (read5["shifra1"].ToString());
                }
                read5.Close();
            }
        }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, that is the connection string used when connecting?

Comment: Also, I would change your password on the database now since you have posted it here...

Comment: {
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstring))
}
also username and password are just sample not real

Answer (score 0):

as i reviewed over the internet i think the problem is in this line of code

any suggestions?

```
var srv1 = new ComboItemExample { DisplayString = "Srv1", ConnectionString = "Data Source=tcp:10.0.0.110;Initial Catalog=Database1;User ID=user;Password=pass;" };
        cmbSrv.Items.Add(srv1);
```